# Get the values of form array with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Have looked quite hard for this answer but having no luck.

I have 3 select lists in a form. The first list is already part of the form, the second two are dynamically added. These select lists are part of an array named event_staff[].

```
<select name="event_staff[]" class="event_staff">
<option value="1">Mark</option>
<option value="2">Sue</option>
</select>

<select name="event_staff[]" class="event_staff">
<option value="1">Mark</option>
<option value="2">Sue</option>
</select>

<select name="event_staff[]" class="event_staff">
<option value="1">Mark</option>
<option value="2">Sue</option>
</select>
```

The user can select a person from each of the lists which are then to be sent via AJAX/Json to a a PHP script which iterates through the array and inserts the selected staff into the database.

For the life of me I dont know how to access the selected values of the lists and send them as an array to the PHP script.

Because the select lists are dynamically created I am not using IDs to access them. I was instead relying on accessing their values by name.

```
select[name='event_staff[]']
```

I had tried this code but the alert is returning empty:

```
var event_staff = new Array();
$("select[name='event_staff[]']:selected").each(function() {
event_staff.push($this).attr('value');
});
alert(event_staff);
```

Thanks.

Solved with the following, but not sure if its pretty or not:

```
var event_staff = new Array();
$('select[name="event_staff[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
event_staff.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Just seems I needed the option:selected. While this doesnt seem to create an array, I have exploded the variable in the PHP on the delimiter and created the array that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var event_staff = [];
$("select[name='event_staff[]'] option:selected").each(function () {
    event_staff.push( this.value );
});
alert(event_staff);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6Fk/

---

If you instead want the name of that person, use `.text()`:

```
var event_staff = [];
$("select[name='event_staff[]'] option:selected").each(function() {
    event_staff.push( $.text(this) );
});
alert(event_staff);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6Fk/1/

---

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var event_staff = $("select[name='event_staff[]'] option:selected").map(function() {
    return $.text(this);
}).get();
alert(event_staff);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6Fk/2/

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` will return the selected value for select.

```
var event_staff = [];
$('select[name="event_staff[]"]').each(function() {
   event_staff.push($(this).val());
});
alert(event_staff);
```

### The demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fHbaw/